# Настройка webhook, aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, webhook

Помогите настроить webhook для aiogram.

Я настраивал его через flask когда пользовался другой библиотекой. Но сейчас надо переходить.
И есть вопросы, например как почему на гит 2 примера, но в "новом" не передается сертификаты, да и в целом как правильно сделать, мб пример настроенный свой кто-то скинет естественно без данных.

Comment: Уже сделал. Нужно дописать символы.

Comment: Поделись результатом

Comment: @AndreyDolgopolov как исправили?